# Crafty solutions to the following limit

Tags: calculus, limits

The following problem came up at dinner, I know some ways to solve it but they are quite ugly and as some wise man said: There is no place in the world for ugly mathematics.

These methods are using l'Hôpital, but that becomes quite hideous very quickly or by using series expansions.

So I'm looking for slick solutions to the following problem:

> Compute $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\tan x) - \tan(\sin x)}{\arcsin(\arctan x) - \arctan(\arcsin x)}$.

I'm curious what you guys will make of this.

Comment: Can't say much about the limit, but your quote is attributed to G.H. Hardy in "A Mathematician's Apology".

Comment: This might of interest: both the numerator and the denominator are $(-\frac{1}{30}) \ x^7 + O(x^9)$ by Taylor expansion.

Comment: This is item #2 in [Arnold's Trivium](http://www.latroika.com/mathoman/exos/arnold-exos-math.pdf) (French version, translated from Russian Math. Surveys 46:1 (1991)).

Comment: See the discussion at [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20696/a-question-regarding-a-claim-of-v-i-arnold).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Some details get lost because of the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$. I have adjusted this answer to accept $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=a$ to expose those details.

---

If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=a$, then $f'(f^{-1}(0))=f'(0)=a$. Furthermore, if $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $1<k<n$, but $f^{(n)}(0)\not=0$, we can use L'Hopital twice to get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-ax}{x/a-f^{-1}(x)}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)-a}{1/a-1/f'(f^{-1}(x))}\\
&=af'(f^{-1}(0))\;\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)-a}{f'(f^{-1}(x))-a}\\
&=a^2\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f''(x)}{f''(f^{-1}(x))/f'(f^{-1}(x))}\\
&=a^2f'(f^{-1}(0))\;\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f''(x)}{f''(f^{-1}(x))}\\
&=a^3\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f''(x)}{f''(f^{-1}(x))}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Note that if $f^{(k)}(0)=0$, L'Hopital yields
$$
\begin{align}
a^{k+1}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x))}
&=a^{k+1}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f^{(k+1)}(x)}{f^{(k+1)}(f^{-1}(x))/f'(f^{-1}(x))}\\
&=a^{k+1}f'(f^{-1}(0))\;\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f^{(k+1)}(x)}{f^{(k+1)}(f^{-1}(x))}\\
&=a^{k+2}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f^{(k+1)}(x)}{f^{(k+1)}(f^{-1}(x))}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Using $(1)$ and repeating $(2)$, we get that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-ax}{x/a-f^{-1}(x)}=a^{n+1}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{f^{(n)}(f^{-1}(0))}=a^{n+1}\tag{3}
$$
Suppose $g^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $0\le k<m$ and $g^{(m)}(0)\not=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{h(x)}{x}=1$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g^{(k)}(h(x))}{g^{(k)}(x)}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g^{(k+1)}(h(x))h'(x)}{g^{(k+1)}(x)}\\
&=h'(0)\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g^{(k+1)}(h(x))}{g^{(k+1)}(x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g^{(k+1)}(h(x))}{g^{(k+1)}(x)}\\
&=\frac{g^{(m)}(h(0))}{g^{(m)}(0)}\\
&=1\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

To finish things off, let $f(x)=\sin(\tan(\arcsin(\arctan(x))))$, $h(x)=\tan(\sin(x))$, and $a=1$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\tan(x))-\tan(\sin(x))}{\arcsin(\arctan(x))-\arctan(\arcsin(x))}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(h(x))-ah(x)}{h^{-1}(x/a)-h^{-1}(f^{-1}(x))}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(h(x))-ah(x)}{h(x)/a-f^{-1}(h(x))}\frac{h(x)/a-f^{-1}(h(x))}{x/a-f^{-1}(x)}\frac{x/a-f^{-1}(x)}{h^{-1}(x/a)-h^{-1}(f^{-1}(x))}\\
&=a^{n+1}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
because
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(h(x))-ah(x)}{h(x)/a-f^{-1}(h(x))}=a^{n+1}
$$
by $(3)$, and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{h(x)/a-f^{-1}(h(x))}{x/a-f^{-1}(x)}=1
$$
by $(4)$ using $g(x)=x/a-f^{-1}(x)$, and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x/a-f^{-1}(x)}{h^{-1}(x/a)-h^{-1}(f^{-1}(x))}=\frac{1}{1/h'(h^{-1}(0))}=1
$$

---

**Summary:** Letting $g(x)=ah(x)$, we get that if
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)}{x}=a
$$
and $f^{(k)}(0)=g^{(k)}(0)$ for $1<k<n$, but $f^{(n)}(0)\not=g^{(n)}(0)$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x)}=a^{n+1}
$$

---

**Simpler approach:** Convinced that there must be a simpler approach, I have revisited this answer.

For some $n>1$, assume

1. $f,g\in C^n$
2. $f^{(k)}(0)=g^{(k)}(0)$ for $k< n$ and $f^{(n)}(0)\not=g^{(n)}(0)$
3. $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=a\not=0$

These assumptions imply that $f(x)=ax+O(x^2)$ and $g(x)=ax+O(x^2)$.

Furthermore, $f^{-1}(x)=x/a+O(x^2)$ and $g^{-1}(x)=x/a+O(x^2)$.

Assumption 2 implies that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x^n}=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)-g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\not=0\tag{6}
$$
Substituting $x\mapsto f^{-1}(x)$ and using $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{g(g^{-1}(x))-g(f^{-1}(x))}{g^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x)}=g'(0)=a$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x^n}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(f^{-1}(x))-g(f^{-1}(x))}{f^{-1}(x)^n}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(g^{-1}(x))-g(f^{-1}(x))}{f^{-1}(x)^n}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a(g^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x))}{(x/a)^n}\\
&=a^{n+1}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x^n}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Dividing both sides of $(7)$ by $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{g^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x^n}$ yields
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x)}=a^{n+1}\tag{8}
$$

Comment: Well done! This is a L'Hopital solution, but then nicer than the one I had. One could also fill in odd-degree polynomials (since that will be the series expansion) and get the result. I wonder if there is a nicer trick.

Comment: +1 A very nice approach! Quite concise, elegant and to the point.

Comment: Why $f′(f^{-1}(0))=f′(0)=a$?

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=a$ implies $f(0)=0$, which means $f^{-1}(0)=0$. Furthermore, it means that $f'(0)=a$.

Comment: I still don't fully comprehend why $f(0) = 0$ derives from the limit.

Comment: For all $x$ close to $0$, $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is close to $a$, that means $f(x)$ is between $\left(a-\frac12\right)x$ and $\left(a+\frac12\right)x$, then apply the Squeeze Theorem as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 4):

We can proceed by Taylor expansion, which is the best way in this case, and we have

- $\tan x=x+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^7}{315}+O(x^9) $
- $\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+O(x^9) $
- $\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+O(x^9) $
- $\arcsin x=x+\frac{x^3}6+\frac{3x^5}{40}+\frac{5x^7}{112}+O(x^9) $

and then

- $ \sin(\tan x)=x+\frac{x^3}6-\frac{x^5}{40}-\frac{55x^7}{1008}+O(x^9)$
- $ \tan(\sin x)=x+\frac{x^3}6-\frac{x^5}{40}-\frac{107x^7}{5040}+O(x^9)$
- $ \arcsin(\arctan x)=x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{13x^5}{120}-\frac{341x^7}{5040}+O(x^9)$
- $ \arctan(\arcsin x)=x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{13x^5}{120}-\frac{173x^7}{5040}+O(x^9)$

and therefore

$$\frac{\sin(\tan x) - \tan(\sin x)}{\arcsin(\arctan x) - \arctan(\arcsin x)} =\frac{-\frac{55x^7}{1008}+\frac{107x^7}{5040}+O(x^9)}{-\frac{341x^7}{5040}+\frac{173x^7}{5040}+O(x^9)}=\frac{-168+O(x^2)}{-168+O(x^2)}\to 1$$