# calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to0} \frac{\sin(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)}{\arcsin(\arctan x)-\arctan(\arcsin x)}$

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crafty solutions to the following limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80364/crafty-solutions-to-the-following-limit)

A problem in a trivium was:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)}{\arcsin(\arctan x)-\arctan(\arcsin x)}$$

Comment: If I am not mistaken this is a problem from Arnold. A google search or something can give a quick answer on this. The result is -1.

Comment: @ChangweiZhou : Who is Arnold?

Comment: @V.I.Arnold. Also apologize for confusing the sign.

Comment: I knew I'd seen this before *here*: [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/80364/742).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this article:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20696/a-question-regarding-a-claim-of-v-i-arnold

Comment: Especially Robert Israel’s answer, which makes the right intuition crystal clear.

Comment: That's called a classic trick question-it tricks you into overthinking the problem. This is why recognizing patterns is so important in practical problem solving!