# How to find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\tan x-\tan\sin x}{7x^7}$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> How to find 
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\tan x-\tan\sin x}{7x^7}?$$

L’Hopital rule does not work because derivative of numerator goes very wide and I need to take 7? Can somebody show me other way of finding it?

Comment: Taylor expand $\sin(\tan x)$ and $\tan(\sin x)$ out to order $x^7$.  The first six orders will match; the difference is then $kx^7$ and your answer is $k/7$.

Comment: It reminds me somehow the [old Arnold's problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80364/crafty-solutions-to-the-following-limit).

Comment: the solution should be $$-\frac{1}{210}$$