# Why solving this limit like this is wrong and how to correctly solve it

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I am taking a Calculus 1 class and one exercise asks to solve the following limit:

$$
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\tan x) - \tan(\sin x)}{\arcsin(\arctan x) - \arctan(\arcsin x)}
$$

Seeing as both parts of the division go to $0$, I decided to try L'Hopital, but after deriving everything twice (and still getting $\frac{0}{0}$) I gave up (it didn't seem like it would get me anywhere).

After that I tried the following:

$$
g(x) = \arcsin(\arctan x) - \arctan(\arcsin x)
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\tan x)}{g(x)} - \frac{\tan (\sin x)}{g(x)}
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\tan x)}{\tan x} \frac{\tan x}{g(x)} - \frac{\tan (\sin x)}{\sin x} \frac{\sin x}{g(x)}
$$

And since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\tan x)}{\tan x} = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan (\sin x)}{\sin x} = 1$:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{g(x)} - \frac{\sin x}{g(x)}
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} \frac{x}{g(x)} - \frac{\sin x}{x} \frac{x}{g(x)}
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{g(x)} - \frac{x}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} 0 = 0
$$

But the bad part is that this is wrong, the answer should be 1 and not 0. I have no clue where I went wrong, and worse still, I have no clue how to solve this exercise another way. Where did I go wrong? How could I solve this?

Comment: Here's a video where professor Borcherds discuss this limit https://youtu.be/lov2nhJdPqw

Comment: Without those replacements by $1$, the limit would be

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left[\frac{\sin(\operatorname{tg}(x))}{\operatorname{tg}(x)}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{tg}(x)}x-\frac{\operatorname{tg}(\sin(x))}{\sin(x)}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}x\right]\frac{x}{g(x)}$$

The difference tends to $0$, but [$\frac x{g(x)}$ tends to $-\infty$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BDivide%5Bx%2CArcSin%5BArcTan%5Bx%5D%5D-ArcTan%5BArcSin%5Bx%5D%5D%5D%2Cx-%3E0%5D) when $x\to 0$.

Comment: Compose Taylor series from inside to outside

Comment: Refer to the duplicate here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80364